# Hidden input fields not getting serialized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I have some hidden fields on a form in which I assign a value to it later on using javascript.  However when I go to post the form to my controller which accepts a FormCollection as a paramter it does not seem to pick up the hidden fields, only the visible input fields.

```
 <div id="deviceInfoPanel" class="panel-body">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Settings", "EditDatasource", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "__dsAjaxAntiForgeryForm", @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div id="deviceinfo">
                    <!--This is where the device info content will be created
                        This will be created dynmically by making an AJAX call
                        to the server bringing back the information required
                        to construct the HTML dynamically via javascript.-->
                    @Html.Hidden("dsID");
                    @Html.Hidden("dsName");
                    @Html.Hidden("dsDesc");
                    @Html.Hidden("dsOID");
                    @Html.Hidden("dsMetric");
                    @Html.Hidden("dsValueMin");
                    @Html.Hidden("dsValueMax");
                    @Html.Hidden("dsAlertThreshold");
                    @Html.Hidden("dsNoData");
                    @Html.Hidden("dsAlertTrigInt");
                    @Html.Hidden("dsAlertClearInt");
                    @Html.Hidden("dsAlertSubject");
                    @Html.Hidden("dsAlertBody");
                    @Html.Hidden("dsDeletedDP");
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Apply" id="postEditDatasource" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
```

and here is my ajax post method

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#postEditDatasource').click(function (event) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(deletedDatapoints));
    //serialise and assign json data to hidden field
    $('#dsDeletedDP').val(JSON.stringify(deletedDatapoints));

    //anti forgery token
    //get the form
    var form = $('#__dsAjaxAntiForgeryForm');
    //from the form get the antiforgerytoken
    var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();

    var URL = '/Settings/EditDatasource';
    console.log(form);
    //we make an ajax call to the controller on click
    //because the controller has a AntiForgeryToken attribute
    //we need to get the token from the form and pass it with the ajax call.
    //__RequestVerificationToken: token,
    $('#__dsAjaxAntiForgeryForm').on('submit', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            data: form.serializeArray(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (result) {
                alert('this worked')
                if (result.result == "Error") {
                    ShowDatasourcePostAlert('failPost', 3000);
                } else {
                    ShowDatasourcePostAlert('successPost', 3000);
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(jqXHR + ', ' + textStatus + ', ' + errorThrown);
            }
        })
        return false;
    })
});
```

})

Comment: `serializeArray` method serialize hidden fields as any other field. I'm afraid problem should be something else.

Comment: Can you use the browser's dev tools, specifically the `Network` tab, in order to see what data is being sent to the server for the `POST`? That should show you all the data picked up from the form, and you can see exactly whether the hidden fields are being passed to the server.

Comment: I have exactly this issue, no problem with there's no hidden type, but with it, it won't work.